# Angular 7: How to populate custom table component

Tags: angular, components, angular7, custom-component

I have this custom table component that I need to use in another component:

CustomTable.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { User } from 'src/app/shared/Models/user.model';

@Component({
  selector: "app-nguserslist",
  templateUrl: "./nguserslist.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./nguserslist.component.scss"]
})
export class NguserslistComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() users: User[];

  constructor() {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
   }
}
```

CustomTable.html:

```
<div ibmGrid>
    <div ibmRow>
      <div ibmCol [columnNumbers]="{'lg':12}">
          <section class="bx--structured-list">
              <div class="bx--structured-list-thead">
                <div class="bx--structured-list-row bx--structured-list-row--header-row">
                    <div class="bx--structured-list-th">Users</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="bx--structured-list-tbody">
                      <div class="bx--structured-list-row" *ngFor="let user of users">
                        <tr>
                          <div class="bx--structured-list-td">{{user.UserName}}
                          </div>
                        </tr>
                          <!-- <div class="bx--structured-list-td">{{user.Email}}</div> -->
                      </div>
              </div>
            </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need to use that table in another component and populate it with a  userslist obtained in the component where I need to use this list. That component is:

userManager.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { User } from "src/app/shared/Models/user.model";
import { Profile } from "src/app/shared/Models/profile";
import { UsermanagerService } from "../usermanager.service";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { IfStmt } from "@angular/compiler";

@Component({
  selector: "app-user-manager",
  templateUrl: "./user-manager.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./user-manager.component.scss"]
})
export class UserManagerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() user: User[];
  users: User[];
  http: any;
  profiles: any = {};
  profile: Profile[];

  constructor(
    public actRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    public router: Router,
    private userManagerService: UsermanagerService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.userManagerService.getUsers().subscribe((data: User[]) => {
      this.users = data;
    });
  }
```

The `getUsers()` method provides the list of users that I need to render with my custom table component

and theres is the UserManager.html:

```
<div class="bx--grid" style="height: 80%;">
  <div class="bx--row border-bottom-internal-layout">
    <div class="bx--col-lg-12 column-padding">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link"
                 [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
                 [routerLink]="['./tracks']">Tracks
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link"
                 [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
                 [routerLink]="['./albums']">Albums
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bx--row" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="bx--col-lg-3 border-right-internal-layout column-padding">
      // HERE SHOULD GO THE CUSTOM TABLE
    </div>
    <div class="bx--col-lg-9 column-padding">
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've already tried to declare on the `UserManager.ts` a variable like this:

```
userList = new CustomTable(this.users);
```

but it didn't work. How can I use my custom table on the UserManager controller rendering the usersList that the `GetUsers()` method brings?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: Here's the error got with the solution proposed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use the routing strategy, then add the component to routes and implement the getUsers() method within the component itself.

If the component takes only the array of users and renders it.

1. Declare the component in the module.
2. Import the module into the consuming module.
3. Include the selector in HTML
4. Add ngIf to the selector and pass the input value.

> ```
>       <app-nguserslist *ngIf="users.length > 0" [users]="users" ></app-nguserslist>
> ```

UserManager.html:

```
<div class="bx--grid" style="height: 80%;">
  <div class="bx--row border-bottom-internal-layout">
    <div class="bx--col-lg-12 column-padding">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link"
                 [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
                 [routerLink]="['./tracks']">Tracks
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link"
                 [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
                 [routerLink]="['./albums']">Albums
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bx--row" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="bx--col-lg-3 border-right-internal-layout column-padding">
      // HERE SHOULD GO THE CUSTOM TABLE
      <app-nguserslist *ngIf="users.length > 0" [users]="users" ></app-nguserslist>
    </div>
    <div class="bx--col-lg-9 column-padding">
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My idea is not to implement the GetUsers on the method itselft to make it reusable. I've tried the second approach but it doesn't render the list, and the console brings an error: "_co.users is undefined"

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the error or any detailed log of it